# How can I correct the rusting as seen here on deck railing?

Tags: wood, deck, decking

I have a couple of questions.

I have gotten tradepersons to install new deck railing back in Dec 2018. So it is about 2.5 years old.

However I can already see some rust sipping out to the surface. One of the veridical wood plank is also bending.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question 1.**

Is it an indication of poor workmanship or material? I just want to understand if it can be totally avoidable in the first place, so I will not repeat the same mistake next time. Not to assign blame.

**Question 2.**

If I want to rectify the situation, what can I do? For the rust mark, I am planning to apply some outdoor paint. Is it enough?

Comment: Seem like they are nail holes.  Guessing that common nails were used instead of coated or galvanize nails.  Unless expecting remove and change nails, then a good sanding, filling of holes with wood filler and then primer and paint.

Comment: And a drop of shellac or Kilz primer to reduce recurrence of rust.